# Help: How to format .NET date string to NSDate?

Tags: .net, objective-c

I have a .net string that looks like this 7/7/2011 12:00:00 AM.

How can I convert this to NSDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        NSDateFormatter *frmtr=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [frmtr setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
        NSDate *datefr = [frmtr dateFromString:@"7/7/2011 12:00:00 AM"];
        NSString *dates=[frmtr stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSLog(@"datefr%@",datefr);
        NSLog(@"dates%@",dates);
        [frmtr release];
```